# Can't get CardView inside ListView to display corner radius or shadow

Tags: android, listview, androidx, cardview

I'm trying desperately to get a shadow to appear all around for my CardView that's embedded in a ListView (as well as a corner radius on that card).

Here is my main layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="...android.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/summary_list_view"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                ></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my list view item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/shadowed_container_view"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:padding="15dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:contentPadding="10dp"
app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp"
android:outlineProvider="bounds"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Testing">

    </TextView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

hardwareAccelerated is also in my manifest so it's definitely not that.

But this is all I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to fix the shadow issue by embedding the CardView's in a LinearLayout (I guess that's what allows the layout margin to take effect). However, I've still be unable to get the corner radius to show.

Edit: so it appears that calling setBackgroundColor() on a CardView disables the rounded radius. So by changing that to setCardBackgroundColor() I was able to get the border radius back.

Hope this helps someone else.